# Добавить scroll на pop-up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как добавить scroll на pop-up блок без полос прокрутки т.е. не используя overflow: scroll;. На данный момент pop-up блок не влазит полностью в область окна по высоте, а при скролле срабатывает сам документ. Содержимое обрезается - его не видно.

```css
.popup {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 20;
  margin: 0;
  width: 85%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 40vw;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #383838;
  background: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 14px/18px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  position: fixed;
  cursor: default;
}

.overlay:target {
  display: block;
}

.overlay:target+.popup {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 20%;
}

.close {
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 13px/20px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all ease .8s;
}

.close:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  content: "X";
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  font-size: 12px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: rgba(252, 20, 0, 0.8);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.popup embed,
.popup iframe {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
  <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="win1"></a>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="wrapper-p1-block">
      <div class="pop-img">
        <img src="/images/team/52.png" alt="Ivan Ivanych">
      </div>
      <div class="pop-txt">
        <p>Ivan Ivanych<br>
          <span>Founder</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-p2-block">
      <div class="pop-txt-1">
        <h3>some text</h3>
        <p>some text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pop-txt-2">
        <p>some text</p>
      </div>
      <a class="close" title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение, но оно не кросбраужерное(нет поддерки Fifefox и IE):

```
.popup::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Для совместимости с Fifefox и IE нужно пробовать [полифилы]. (https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar)

[Сылка](https://caniuse.com/#search=webkit-scrollbar) на CanIUse.